# Is the code for sorting a std::vector<std::string> by length correct in C++20?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, c++20, std-ranges

I wrote a code that sorts vector strings by length. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether it will work in the next standard in this form. Is this the correct code in C++20?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ranges> 
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> words = {"std", "vector", "string", "optional", "clamp"};

    // C++11
    // std::sort(words.begin(), words.end(), 
    //     [](auto& lhs, auto& rhs) { return lhs.length() < rhs.length(); });

    // maybe C++20?
    using namespace std::ranges;
    sort(words, {}, size); // or 'sort(words, less{}, size);'

    for (auto& word : words) {
        std::cout << word << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: The C++11 version is going to keep working. They obviously won't break all C++ code that has ever been written.

Comment: Out of curiosity - how come the `size` argument is being deduced to anything relevant? Is it deduced to be `std::string::size` or `std::ranges::size`? How come we can omit the `&`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine and compiles under the upcoming GCC 10.

As @Ayxan points out, C++20 will still have the usual algorithms, so you don't need to change your code if you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

When you have some code using only standard or very-commonly-used libraries, you can try compiling it with newer compilers and experimental standard versions, on sites like:

- Compiler Explorer - https://godbolt.org/
- Coliru ("COmpile, LInk and RU") - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

and others.